# HTML / CSS - Hover Link Color

Tags: html, css, colors, hover, hex

I have this code written in my CSS; which makes all links on my site white, and when they're hovered on, they turn gray.

```
a:link {color: #FFFFFF}
a:active {color: #383838}
a:visited {color: #FFFFFF}
a:hover {color: #383838}
```

Here's the portion of my site which has links that are white and turn gray when hovered on. I have four different links on the site separated by a "|" . I am trying to make each link STAY white, but change to a different HTML color whenever they're hovered on….to match our logo. (HTML section of the code that has my links are attached below).

[Page 1](http://www.my-website09090909.com/page1) **|** [Page 2](http://www.my-website09090909.com/page2) **|** [Page 3](http://www.my-website09090909.com/page3) **|** [Page 4](http://www.mywebsite09090909.com/page4)

I would love if someone could help me figure out a very easy, simple way to make each link, Page 1, Page 2, Page 3 and Page 4, each change different HTML colors when they're hovered on. Basically, a rule or something that says the link named Page 1 needs to be colored #C7C025 when hovered on…and the link named Page 2 needs to be colored #950285 when hovered on and so forth…

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your links an ID:

```
<a id="page1" href="http://www.my-website09090909.com/page1">Page 1</a>
<a id="page2" href="http://www.my-website09090909.com/page1">Page 2</a>
<!-- .... -->
```

And then use this css:

```
#page1:hover { color: red; }
#page2:hover { color: blue; }
/* ... */
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. Very simple and worked on the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a parent element and according to your parent element try below :

Just try this :

```
<div id="links">
<a href="http://www.my-website09090909.com/page1">Page 1</a> 
<b><span class="separator">|</span></b> 
<a href="http://www.my-website09090909.com/page2">Page 2</a> 
<b><span class="separator">|</span></b> 
<a href="http://www.my-website09090909.com/page3">Page 3</a> 
<b><span class="separator">|</span></b> 
<a href="http://www.mywebsite09090909.com/page4">Page 4</a>
</div>
```

And CSS Is :

```
<style type="text/css">
#links a:nth-of-type(1){color:#009900;}
#links a:nth-of-type(1):hover{color:#ccc;}
#links a:nth-of-type(2){color:#006699 ;}
#links a:nth-of-type(2):hover{color:#ccc;}
#links a:nth-of-type(3){color:#990000;}
#links a:nth-of-type(3):hover{color:#ccc;}
#links a:nth-of-type(4){color:#FF00CC;}
#links a:nth-of-type(4):hover{color:#ccc;}
</style>
```

Comment: would there be a reason for using this over the id method?

Comment: @btevfik, no, we can also go with separate id for each link, i just posted this answer as another way of doing this thing. That's it

Comment: @btevfik: You need less HTML code. On the other hand, with IDs you are independent from the order of your links, if you plan to reorder them.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell The id method won't work with old browsers as well? Or just the method above?