# how to change color of href on hover

Tags: html, css, jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following code in my jsp:

```
<a href="#expProd" id="${model.product.actualT[status.index].Id}" class="highlight"><spring:message code="label.actual.expand" /></a> 
                                                                                </div>
```

Basically i have to change the color to  orange when the mouse is over the label and blue 
as default color. I know how to do it using an id attribute as indicated in this post([HTML / CSS - Hover Link Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458313/html-css-hover-link-color)however) since my id is  generated as shown below i can't use it:

```
id="${model.product.actualT[status.index].Id}"
```

Any idea how to do it please? I tried using the class tag but it is not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tinkered with a selector like .. `a[href=#expProd]:hover { color: orange; } ` . This is bare minimum, there's a ton of other variables to really dial it in - but this should work too ( http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-links-depending-on-destination/ ). Also, what ID is that spitting out? And I am assuming you have other items with the `.highlight` class so you can't target that?

Comment: <a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>

a:hover{
  color:red;
}

Comment: what was your css for the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pumg7cbk/)

```
.highlight:hover{
color:red;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Sorry will do so in future, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer I have added the jsp content for future reference

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use additional class selector in css

```
a.highlight:link {color: #FFFFFF}
   a.highlight:active {color: #383838}
   a.highlight:visited {color: #FFFFFF}
   a.highlight:hover {color: #383838}
```