# Changing Hover Color CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

In this [Website](http://renunion.com) there are 4 tabs at the home page. How can i change the green-blueish color when i hover the mouse on a tab?

```
a {
    -webkit-transition-property: color;
    -moz-transition-property: color;
    transition-property: color;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
a {
    color: #00e1b6;
    line-height: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

Comment: with `a:hover { color:#xxxxxx;}`

Comment: This question is lacking a complete example of the problem and once you have changed the live site, this question becomes useless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML / CSS - Hover Link Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458313/html-css-hover-link-color)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following css rule at the end of your `css` file to change `background-color`. `important` is needed because it is already being used in your `css`. So we need to use it again to override previous styling.

**Note:** use of `!important` is considered bad practice and it should be avoided as much as we can.

```
.header:hover {
    background: #7cedd7 !important;
}
```

Comment: No. `!important` is not the answer here, and is considered bad practice. The problem is that `#service .header is more specific than `.header:hover`. One alternate solution could be to use `#section header:hover` as the selector for the hover. I suggest reading about [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: @andyb Exactly what I was going to point out. I think you should put an answer about `CSS specifity` because the OP can loop in bad practices if he always use `!important` when some property of `CSS` does not change.

Comment: @Error404 ok, done. I was hoping that my comment would be enough to prompt an answer edit... also your message highlighted that I screwed up my code escaping in my comment. I assume this question will be deleted anyway since since there is no lasting example of the problem. The OP has already changed the live site!

Comment: yes, i agree `important` is bad to use. I suggested it only because it was already being used in css written by previous developer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `#service .header` is [*more specific*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `.header:hover` so the more specific rule is always overriding the `:hover`. See [CSS: Specificity Wars](https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) on how some of the selectors combine to override each other.

One solution could be to use `#section header:hover` as the selector for the hover dynamic pseudo class

```
#section header:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

Note: adding `!important` is considered bad practice - see [What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3706819/637889)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below CSS to change the hover color. As for all for the main div is with class "box" and inner width with the class "header"

```
.box. header:hover {
    background: #7cedd7;
}
```